# Add timestamp and UserID when a checkbox is ticked

Tags: microsoft-word

I've build an onboarding checklist for my human resources department. It has things to do like "Employment Agreement" and "Safety Handbook", and checkmarks next to each of the to-dos.

What I need is a way to insert text with EACH to-do with the USERID of the computer that ticked the box, and a timestamp telling me when it was done. It would look something like this:

```
[**X**] Completed Onboarding conversation with John Smith (*Completed by Jane Doe on 9/1/16 3:00PM*)
[**X**] Completed I-9 onboarding for John Smith (*Completed by John Doe on 9/6/16 10:00 AM*)
```

Admittedly, I am not the greatest with VBA, and any VBA experience I had is with Excel and not Word, so some hand-holding would be appreciated.'

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119724/word-checkbox-contentcontol-onchange-event

Comment: Hi there. Unfortunately we're not a script-writing service, but can/will help with specifics if you get stuck while writing your script.  Where exactly are you getting stuck implementing your script?  And what have you tried already to get past that point (and what were the results)?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have 0 code thus far. I appreciate the candid response. I've got a few other sources to look for help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My answer to [another recent question](https://superuser.com/questions/1139731/) includes info that might help you here. I used one of the legacy ActiveX controls to insert a timestamp when a button is clicked. You could presumably do something similar by inserting a legacy ActiveX Check Box control, and then attaching a bit of code that goes to end of that paragraph (equivalent to pressing the End key) and, instead of inserting just the timestamp, inserts the string '(Completed by' + current user ID + 'on' + current date/time + ')' when the check box is selected.

**Update:** I just quickly tested this by recording a macro of pressing End and typing the text/inserting the USERNAME field and date/time, and then copying the content of that macro to the code for an ActiveX Check Box control that I inserted. It works fine but could use some refinement: as is, it inserts the string every time the check box is clicked; so if I select, clear, and then reselect the check box, the string is inserted 3 times. It's a start though.