# Is it possible to have a time picker content control in Word 2010 that will show the current time when you click on it?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I want to create multiple time fields that will display the current time when you click on it, but won't update when I update the auto increment fields I'm using in the same document. I need something like the date picker content control. I had hope when I saw you could display the date as `h:mm am/pm` but it's kind of pointless, because it only ever displays as`12:00 AM`.

Is there a way I can get the date picker to show the current time when you click on "today" or is there something else I can do?

Comment: Not sure if this meets your needs but how about using a {TIME} [Field Code](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-and-format-field-codes-in-Word-2010-7e9ea3b4-83ec-4203-9e66-4efc027f2cf3) ?

Comment: @Porcupine911 I tried that, but when I update my other fields, the time fields all update to the same current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use TIME field codes. Update each (F9) so that it shows the current time, and then lock it (Ctrl+F11) so that the value doesn't change when you update the other fields in the doc.

If you want some sort of UI element, so that this happens at a mouse click, I just slapped together an *extremely crude* example, where I inserted one of the legacy ActiveX Command Button controls (on the **Developer** tab, click **Legacy Tools** > **Command Button**), added a space after it, and then inserted a TIME field. I then added this rough bit of code to the button (right-click it, and click **View Code**) to move focus off the button, move the cursor 2 spaces to the right (into the field), update and lock the field, and then move focus off the field:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
  Selection.Fields.Update
  Selection.Fields.Locked = True
  Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
End Sub
```

Unless someone manually unlocks the field (Shift+Ctrl+F11), each button can be used only once, making it appropriate for a timestamp, which is what it sounds like you're really after. It's not pretty, but perhaps it's a starting point that you can work into something more sophisticated.

Alternatively, since the time doesn't need to update, the **Insert** tab includes an **Insert Date and Time** button that can insert a timestamp as static text. You could record a macro of clicking the button and selecting the time format you want. Or, to use a Command Button control again, you could add code like this, which just calls **Insert Date and Time** to insert the time immediately after the button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
  Selection.InsertDateTime DateTimeFormat:="h:mm:ss am/pm", InsertAsField:=False, DateLanguage:=wdEnglishUS, CalendarType:=wdCalendarWestern, InsertAsFullWidth:=False
End Sub
```